# MYSQL select all from table where month?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

is it possible to select all fields with some month?

For example: I have column 'create_date' and values of this column:

```
2011-05-06 11:12:13 (this)
2012-06-06 13:12:13
2010-02-06 14:52:13
2011-05-06 21:12:13 (this)
2001-08-06 16:12:13
2011-09-06 18:12:43
2009-01-06 11:12:13
2012-02-06 12:17:55
2010-03-06 14:15:13
2012-05-06 11:19:23 (this)
```

How to select all fields where month equals to 05?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use

```
SELECT create_date FROM table WHERE MONTH(create_date) = 5
```

Comment: actually, Mirgorod wants 5...:)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE month(create_date) = 5
```

look at [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)
This query works on datetime type of column

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(create_date) = 5
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Answer (score 2):

Use  `month(Yourdate)` to extract the month

Answer (score 2):

just stumbled upon something to mention when using MONTH()
it will only get the month from a DATE string. not from a unixtimestamp

if you want to use it with a unixtimestamp try:

```
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(create_date))
```

Answer (score 2):

For a dynamic filtering of the current month :

```
MONTH(create_date) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT
    create_date
FROM
    table
WHERE
    MONTHNAME(create_date) = MONTHNAME(now())
```

Comment: This selects all of the rows that match the current month, but the question is looking for how to select for month 5.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
select create_date from "table" where create_date between '2011-05-01' and '2011-05-31';
```

Comment: Look at question: there're `2011` and `2012` years at example marked as `(this)`