# Incorrect datetime value: '2017-11-%' for column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select records from a month as specified by input string like `"YYYY-MM"`. So I just put `"LIKE $yearMonth-%"` in the query.

It produces below warning:

> "Incorrect datatime value"

But the query seems to be working fine.

I guess it's not the 100% correct way to do it, but it's obviously a very simple and easy way, and aparantly it works... So do I need to bother?

And if so, what would be the easiest way to fix it?

```
<?php
$month = "2017-11";

$query = "SELECT * from table WHERE dates LIKE '{$month}-%'
?>
```

"dates" is of datatype DATETIME

Comment: You should not compare a string with a date. Compare the same data types

Comment: Show us the _entire_ query you are running, and if it contains interpolated PHP variables, then show us an example of the entire raw query you want to run.

Comment: I added code sample.

Answer (score -1):

you could try this solution [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6731882/3652823)

> ```
> SELECT create_date FROM table WHERE MONTH(create_date) = X
> ```

Works the same way with YEAR so you could get your results