# My SQL limiting a search by just the month in a where clause

Tags: mysql

so i need to limit my query by the month 09 in my function but I can't seem to figure out the where portion. i have it written as such

''' select fname, lname, dob as 'Sept Birthdays'
'''from student
'''where dob  = '%09%'
'''order by name;

everything I seem to be reading on this site and in my notes doesn't really give me a working answer. as I have the data in the table itself as a yyyy-mm-dd format I just want the mm. any help?

the table set I'm working with is this [table set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asyAy.png) 
these are all fake names btw so I'm not giving out any information.
sorry if this is a duplicate but I cant find the duplicate hence this question.

Comment: I think you want `like`, not `=`.  See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp.  Also you probably want to be careful about not matching the ninth day or year.

Comment: If the "dob" field is actually stored as a data field, you can use the MONTH() function.  eg. MONTH(dob) = 9.  Or if your "dob" field is just a string, then MONTH(DATE(dob)) = 9 should do the trick

Comment: I got it thanks guys!

Comment: Note SO supports markup (both Markdown and HTML) to automatically format (and highlight) code. When you post (or edit your post), there are buttons to apply such formatting and in-editor help explaining the formatting. Site help should also have pages explaining the markup. Why not try it with this question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL select all from table where month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731854/mysql-select-all-from-table-where-month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column that a data is of type date? If so, you can use this query.

I made this query based on yours, anything is just you adapt.

```
SELECT fname, lname, dob AS 'Sept Birthdays' 
  FROM student 
  WHERE MONTH(dob) = 9 
  ORDER BY name DESC;
```

`ORDER BY` can be used with `DESC` or `ASC` for descending or ascending order (respectively).

- MOUNT(column) = value // for searches by month
- YEAR(column) = value // for searches by year
- DAY(column) = value // for searches by day

Obs: You can use together for example YEAR and MONTH

Note that, as the column data isn't directly compared but instead is passed through a function, [indices](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) on `student.dob` in general can't be used, which will impact query performance. If this is important, see "[Is it possible to have function-based index in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10595037/90527)".

Comment: Note though that functions cannot use indexes